# Split a Matrix file into multiple files based on column name

Tags: python, r

I have a large tab delimited file with thousands of columns and many thousands of line. It looks like:

```
ID  A_1 A_2 A_3 B_1 B_3 B_4 C_2 C_3 C_5
xx  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09
xy  03  05  33  44  15  26  27  08  09
```

I want to split this table in to multiple files:

```
# A.txt
ID A_1 A_2 A_3
xx 01  02  03
xy 03  05  33  

# B.txt
ID B_1 B_3 B_4
xx 04  05  06
xy 44  15  26  

# C.txt
ID C_2 C_3 C_5
xx 07  08  09
xy 27  08  09
```

So, file name would be the column header prefix. Id column is fixed in each file. Rest of the columns in each file is based on common prefix before underscore.

How can I do it in Linux/Bash/Perl/python command?

Comment: Have you already tried solving this yourself? Did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: @simbabque. When I posted the answer, there was an `R` tag.

Comment: You replaced that tag with the _awk_ tag. The likely cause of the downvotes here is that you are asking other people to do your work for you without showing any efforts of your own.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `split.default` on the substring of column names in `R` to a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
nm1 <- sub("_\\d+", "", names(df1)[-1])
lst <- lapply(split.default(df1[-1], nm1), transform, ID = df1$ID)
```

---

Or with `Map`

```
setNames(Map(cbind, ID = df1['ID'], 
     split.default(df1[-1], nm1)), unique(nm1))
#$A
#  ID A_1 A_2 A_3
#1 xx   1   2   3
#2 xy   3   5  33

#$B
#  ID B_1 B_3 B_4
#1 xx   4   5   6
#2 xy  44  15  26

#$C
#  ID C_2 C_3 C_5
#1 xx   7   8   9
#2 xy  27   8   9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("xx", "xy"), A_1 = c(1L, 3L), A_2 = c(2L, 
5L), A_3 = c(3L, 33L), B_1 = c(4L, 44L), B_3 = c(5L, 15L), B_4 = c(6L, 
26L), C_2 = c(7L, 27L), C_3 = c(8L, 8L), C_5 = c(9L, 9L)),
class = data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks. How to read table File (myfile.txt) and save multiple files automatically by column prefix name after splitting at a time in R? Let me know full code. Learning R. Otherwise, other than R code would be helpful.

Comment: @Jishan  The dataset is split into a `list`.  You can use `lapply` to loop through the `list` (or a `for` loop) to read multiple files i.e. `lapply(filenames, read.table)` into a `list`

Comment: Thanks. I am new for R. How to save multiple files automatically by column prefix name after splitting at a time in R? Let me know full code please

Comment: @Jishan  Try this `lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.csv(paste0(x, ".csv"), lst[[x]], row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))`

Comment: df1 <- as.data.frame(read.table("MyFile.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE));

nm <- sub("_\\d+", "", names(df1)[-1]);

sp <- setNames(Map(cbind, ID = df1['ID'], split.default(df1[-1], nm)), unique(nm));

lapply(names(sp), function(x) write.table(sp[[x]], paste0(x, ".tsv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep="\t"))

Comment: @Jishan Not clear about your comment